Peak in access log when playing around with cookie consent
One day we made some tests with cookie consent, including disabling it for a short time and switching to another cookie banner provider.
On this day, the requests and unique users in server's access log raised about 20% (as reported by GoAccess). Same for the counts reported by Google Analytics.
It's obvious that this peak is related to the changes in cookie consent behavior.
How can a change in cookie consent affect the access log? Accepting/declining cookies only effects third-party resources. Those are requested from another server and therefore do not appear in the access logs. What am I overseeing?
EDIT GoAccess counts unique users based on ip, date and user-agent. It has nothing to do with any tracking cookie mechanism. That's exactly why I do not understand how cookie consent changes have an effect on the access log.

I'd presume the way you measure "unique users" depends on a tracking cookie. In some jurisdictions like the EU, the user's consent isn't required just for third-party cookies, but for non-required first-party cookies as well.

@ceejayoz No. GoAccess uses access logs as a source and counts unique users based on ip, date and user-agent. It has nothing to do with the user's consent state.

If you're implementing cookie consent to comply with GDPR, you shouldn't be using IP addresses in logs for analytics purposes at all unless the users have affirmatively consented to that, too.
